# jquery not working after ajax post asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am doing a post back to get a partial view using ajax following is the code I am using to render the partial view in a div called 'DivSearchGrid'.

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" >
       $('#Retrieve').click(function () {
           $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'Search');
           //                      $('form').submit();
           var formSubmit = $('form');
           var datTab;
           $.ajax({
               url: "/AuthorityGrid/Search",
               type: "POST",
               data: formSubmit.serialize(),
               success: function (data) {
                   datTab = data;
               },
               complete: function () {
                   $('#DivSearchGrid').html(datTab);

               }

           })
           return false;
       });
   </script>
```

The action method in the controller returns a grid with new values. my problem is that after the ajx call is complete the other jquery events in my page stop working. The code for some events is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            //$('th[scope|="col"]').resizable();
            $("#resultGrid > tbody").selectable({
                selected: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.selected.cells != null) {
                        var strAmount = ui.selected.cells(6).innerText;
                        var Amount = strAmount.replace(/,/gi, "");
                        var keyValue = "AuthorityLevel1=" + ui.selected.cells(11).innerText + ",AuthorityLevel2=" + ui.selected.cells(12).innerText + ",TcmAccount=" + ui.selected.cells(2).innerText + ",TcmType=" + ui.selected.cells(10).innerText + ",Rating=" + ui.selected.cells(5).innerText + ",Amount=" + Amount + ",AuthorityGridKey=" + ui.selected.cells(9).innerText + ",CagName=" + ui.selected.cells(3).innerText
                        var keyValModify = ui.selected.cells(11).innerText + "," + ui.selected.cells(10).innerText + "," + ui.selected.cells(12).innerText + "," + ui.selected.cells(5).innerText + "," + ui.selected.cells(2).innerText + "," + Amount + "," + ui.selected.cells(3).innerText + "," + ui.selected.cells(9).innerText
                        $('#CancelViewParam').val(keyValue);
                        $('#ModifyViewParam').val(keyValModify);

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this function selects a row from the grid and puts the selected values in a hidden field.

Also a function to open popups is not working after the ajax call.code for this function.

```
$(function () {
    $("#DivSearch").dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: "600", width: "600", dialogClass: "myRatingHelp", modal: true });
    $('#bRatingHelperDivSearch').live('click',function () { $('#DivSearch').dialog('open'); });
    $('#DivSearchRating_bOk').click(function () {
    $("#InputAuthorityGridSearch_Rating").val($("#hidRating").val());
    $("#DivSearch").dialog('close');
    });
    $('#DivSearchRating_bCancel').click(function () {
    $("#DivSearch").dialog('close');
    });
    });
```

All these functions work perfectly well before the ajx call but all stop working after the call,can someone help?

Comment: the same was happened with me. but i resolved that issue. let me show you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put your page load jQuery function in one user defined function such as

```
function initializeLoad() {
    $("#DivSearch").dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: "600", width: "600", dialogClass: "myRatingHelp", modal: true });
$('#bRatingHelperDivSearch').live('click',function () { $('#DivSearch').dialog('open'); });
$('#DivSearchRating_bOk').click(function () {
$("#InputAuthorityGridSearch_Rating").val($("#hidRating").val());
$("#DivSearch").dialog('close');
});
$('#DivSearchRating_bCancel').click(function () {
$("#DivSearch").dialog('close');
});
}
initializeLoad();
```

now put script given below at page end :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        initializeLoad();
    }
}
```

below script will call your jQuery page load method everytime when partial postback is done.

above i have given only some of your function. you should put all your necessary function.

external link : http://www.aboutfortunate.com/Technology-Blog.aspx?entid=29

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thnk you for the answer but this does not work for me I get an error that Sys is undefined. I am not using webforms here I am using MVC3

Answer (score 0):

check "/AuthorityGrid/Search" page, if you again include jquery on this page it create problem when second time jquery event. Always include jQuery in main page.

Comment: "/AuthorityGrid/Search" is no a diffrent page I am using mvc and this URl refers to a action methode names search in the same view